# Did Lazers get lazered?

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

Usually chat has our ever ubiquitous Lazers to keep us up to date on the newest questions that have been asked.

As far as I can find, [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5960674#5960674) is our last message from our mothership weapon of doom.  Did something happen to Lazers?  Or does our 20th century technology just require a bit of bashing to get working again?

Comment: Some jerk connected remotely and uploaded a virus :(

Comment: When I see the ♦ symbol, I immediately believe everything I read.

Comment: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5192/9983

Comment: Lazers works fine in the ticker. No one likes tickers though.

Comment: @badp because tickers are stupid. And ugly. And annoying. But mostly stupid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I changed it to ticker and then back to regular feeds. It worked. I have no idea why.